# How to trigger a Firebase function with an HTTP request for reading data from multiple nodes?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

[image: database node]

Consider the above sample image.

Here, in the `users` node there are multiple nodes available under a unique id     *(LcZm1SS7q8aORImjqB6ff9iAi9w1)*.

My job is to read the nodes `node1 & node3` only by passing the unique id and get the data's from those nodes.

How can I achieve this in **Firebase function** with an **HTTP trigger**?

Comment: Do you have an initial attempt (even if it is incomplete or does not work properly)? That may help others to help you.

Comment: @tbrk Yes, of-course I tried. But, I could't succeeded. That's why I post this question.

Comment: I'll be a bit more explicit: put your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `REST-API` Firebase provides.

In your case you would need to do the following requests:

```
https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/LcZm1SS7q8aORImjqB6ff9iAi9w1/node1.json

and

https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/LcZm1SS7q8aORImjqB6ff9iAi9w1/node3.json
```

Make sure to replace `[PROJECT_ID]` with your ID.

You can also request the whole `LcZm1SS7q8aORImjqB6ff9iAi9w1` node and then filter it in the frontend.

```
https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/LcZm1SS7q8aORImjqB6ff9iAi9w1.json
// filter it for your needs
```

---

Please add some code for a more specific answer.